# matplotlib subplot not working as expected

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
horas = [1,2,3,4]
diccionario = {(1,1,2,1):[2,3,4,5],
               (1,2,2,2):[2,5,1,5],
               (1,3,2,3):[2,5,5,5],
               (1,4,2,4):[2,6,8,5],
               (1,5,2,5):[2,7,5,5],
               (1,6,2,6):[2,8,2,5],
               (1,7,2,7):[2,9,6,5],
               (1,8,2,8):[2,4,9,5]}
plt.figure()     
i = 1 
maximo = 0
keys = diccionario.keys()
for n in range(0,len(keys)-1,2):
    gn, = plt.plot(horas,diccionario[keys[n]],'ro-')
    gn1, = plt.plot(horas,diccionario[keys[n+1]],'g*-')
    plt.subplot(len(keys)//2, 1,i)
    plt.legend([gn,gn1], [keys[n],keys[n+1]])
    i+=1
plt.show()
```

I expect to have 4 subplots with two lines each. I have them, but the last one is empty.

Could anyone explain why? I have tried many different ways without succeeding.

Comment: Finally I got it.  Simply put plt.subplot(len(keys)//2, 1,i) before gn, = plt.plot(horas,diccionario[keys[n]],'ro-')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your **subplot()** before you plot **gn** and **gn1**. That will solve your problem.

```
for n in range(0, len(keys) - 1,2):
    plt.subplot(len(keys)//2, 1, i)
    gn, = plt.plot(horas, diccionario[keys[n]], 'ro-')
    gn1, = plt.plot(horas, diccionario[keys[n+1]], 'g*-')
    plt.legend([gn, gn1], [keys[n], keys[n+1]])
    i+=1
```

By the way, I recommend to use **tuple** instead of **dict**. You may notice that the sequence of results is quite different from what you want.